# Call a methods from data()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my Vue App, I use a drag and drop system. (I use https://github.com/Vivify-Ideas/vue-draggable FYI).

In my `data()` I have to declare parameters like this:

```
    data() {
      draggable: {
        dropzoneSelector: 'ul',
        draggableSelector: 'li',
        /* some extra parameters who are no incidence with my problem */
        onDrop: function(event) {
          callLayout(); 
        }
      }
}
```

You can see that I have a `onDrop: function(event) {}`. I would like to call a function I declared like that.

```
  methods: {
    callLayout : function() {
        console.log('TOTO')
    }
  }
```

I tried to use `this.callLayout()` etc.. But still get this error:

> `callLayout` is not a function/not defined.

Do you have an idea of what I'm doing wrong ? =(

Comment: `this.methods.callLayout();` isn't it should have to be?

Comment: @Jai In vue `data`, `computed` properties and `methods` are all accessible by `this.callLayout();` instead of `this.methods.callLayout();`. But you can actually access `this,$methods.callLayout()`, but this is not recommended.

Comment: @Jns, thanks. I actually don't work with vue. So, this i didn't know.

Comment: @Jai And now thanks to eveybody, Iknow.. and you too =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use arrow function or use bind for onDrop function. This gives an error because in onDrop function this keyword does not refers to your component.

```
    data() {
      draggable: {
        dropzoneSelector: 'ul',
        draggableSelector: 'li',
        /* some extra parameters who are no incidence with my problem */
        onDrop: (event)=> { // Chnage to arrow function
          this.callLayout(); // Use this here.
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Perfect... I didn't think that use the old syntax can cause problem like that... ! Thanks a lot !